# jquery ui slider range fix to RTL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I wang to change Jquery slider range to RTL. I am usign this: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

Jquery code:

```
    $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 1000000,
      values: [ 100000, 500000 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val(addCommas(ui.values[1])+ " تومان                " + addCommas(ui.values[0])+" تومان");
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( addCommas( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) )  + " تومان                " + addCommas( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) ) + "تومان" );
  });

  function addCommas(nStr){
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
  }
```

HTML code:

```
<label for="amount">قیمت:</label>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
<input type="text" id="amount" readonly>
```

See image:
[image]

I want to invert the max and min buttons place (RTL).
how to change jquery code or html code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visit the below link for more help:

http://keith-wood.name/rtlSliders.html

Update:

I have updated the above link, as well you can find the RTL CSS and JS below.

The jQuery JS and CSS files:

```js
/*
 * jQuery UI Slider 1.8.9.rtl.1
 *
 * Copyright 2011, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider
 *
 * Depends:
 *  jquery.ui.core.js
 *  jquery.ui.mouse.js
 *  jquery.ui.widget.js
 */
(function($,g){var h=5;$.widget("ui.slider",$.ui.mouse,{widgetEventPrefix:"slide",options:{animate:false,distance:0,max:100,min:0,orientation:"horizontal",isRTL:false,range:false,step:1,value:0,values:null},_create:function(){var f=this,o=this.options;this._keySliding=false;this._mouseSliding=false;this._animateOff=true;this._handleIndex=null;this._detectOrientation();this._mouseInit();this.element.addClass("ui-slider"+" ui-slider-"+this.orientation+(o.isRTL?" ui-slider-rtl":"")+" ui-widget"+" ui-widget-content"+" ui-corner-all");if(o.disabled){this.element.addClass("ui-slider-disabled ui-disabled")}this.range=$([]);if(o.range){if(o.range===true){this.range=$("<div></div>");if(!o.values){o.values=[this._valueMin(),this._valueMin()]}if(o.values.length&&o.values.length!==2){o.values=[o.values[0],o.values[0]]}}else{this.range=$("<div></div>")}this.range.appendTo(this.element).addClass("ui-slider-range");if(o.range==="min"||o.range==="max"){this.range.addClass("ui-slider-range-"+o.range)}this.range.addClass("ui-widget-header")}if($(".ui-slider-handle",this.element).length===0){$("<a href='#'></a>").appendTo(this.element).addClass("ui-slider-handle")}if(o.values&&o.values.length){while($(".ui-slider-handle",this.element).length<o.values.length){$("<a href='#'></a>").appendTo(this.element).addClass("ui-slider-handle")}}this.handles=$(".ui-slider-handle",this.element).addClass("ui-state-default"+" ui-corner-all");this.handle=this.handles.eq(0);this.handles.add(this.range).filter("a").click(function(a){a.preventDefault()}).hover(function(){if(!o.disabled){$(this).addClass("ui-state-hover")}},function(){$(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover")}).focus(function(){if(!o.disabled){$(".ui-slider .ui-state-focus").removeClass("ui-state-focus");$(this).addClass("ui-state-focus")}else{$(this).blur()}}).blur(function(){$(this).removeClass("ui-state-focus")});this.handles.each(function(i){$(this).data("index.ui-slider-handle",i)});this.handles.keydown(function(c){var d=true,index=$(this).data("index.ui-slider-handle"),allowed,curVal,newVal,step;if(f.options.disabled){return}switch(c.keyCode){case $.ui.keyCode.HOME:case $.ui.keyCode.END:case $.ui.keyCode.PAGE_UP:case $.ui.keyCode.PAGE_DOWN:case $.ui.keyCode.UP:case $.ui.keyCode.RIGHT:case $.ui.keyCode.DOWN:case $.ui.keyCode.LEFT:d=false;if(!f._keySliding){f._keySliding=true;$(this).addClass("ui-state-active");allowed=f._start(c,index);if(allowed===false){return}}break}step=f.options.step;if(f.options.values&&f.options.values.length){curVal=newVal=f.values(index)}else{curVal=newVal=f.value()}var e=function(a,b){if(curVal===a){return}newVal=f._trimAlignValue(curVal+b)};switch(c.keyCode){case $.ui.keyCode.HOME:newVal=f._valueMin();break;case $.ui.keyCode.END:newVal=f._valueMax();break;case $.ui.keyCode.PAGE_UP:newVal=f._trimAlignValue(curVal+((f._valueMax()-f._valueMin())/h));break;case $.ui.keyCode.PAGE_DOWN:newVal=f._trimAlignValue(curVal-((f._valueMax()-f._valueMin())/h));break;case $.ui.keyCode.UP:e(f._valueMax(),step);break;case $.ui.keyCode.RIGHT:e(f._valueMax(),f.options.isRTL?-step:step);break;case $.ui.keyCode.DOWN:e(f._valueMin(),-step);break;case $.ui.keyCode.LEFT:e(f._valueMin(),f.options.isRTL?step:-step);break}f._slide(c,index,newVal);return d}).keyup(function(a){var b=$(this).data("index.ui-slider-handle");if(f._keySliding){f._keySliding=false;f._stop(a,b);f._change(a,b);$(this).removeClass("ui-state-active")}});this._refreshValue();this._animateOff=false},destroy:function(){this.handles.remove();this.range.remove();this.element.removeClass("ui-slider"+" ui-slider-horizontal"+" ui-slider-vertical"+" ui-slider-disabled"+" ui-widget"+" ui-widget-content"+" ui-corner-all").removeData("slider").unbind(".slider");this._mouseDestroy();return this},_mouseCapture:function(b){var o=this.options,position,normValue,distance,closestHandle,self,index,allowed,offset,mouseOverHandle;if(o.disabled){return false}this.elementSize={width:this.element.outerWidth(),height:this.element.outerHeight()};this.elementOffset=this.element.offset();position={x:b.pageX,y:b.pageY};normValue=this._normValueFromMouse(position);distance=this._valueMax()-this._valueMin()+1;self=this;this.handles.each(function(i){var a=Math.abs(normValue-self.values(i));if(distance>a){distance=a;closestHandle=$(this);index=i}});if(o.range===true&&this.values(1)===o.min){index+=1;closestHandle=$(this.handles[index])}allowed=this._start(b,index);if(allowed===false){return false}this._mouseSliding=true;self._handleIndex=index;closestHandle.addClass("ui-state-active").focus();offset=closestHandle.offset();mouseOverHandle=!$(b.target).parents().andSelf().is(".ui-slider-handle");this._clickOffset=mouseOverHandle?{left:0,top:0}:{left:b.pageX-offset.left-(closestHandle.width()/2),top:b.pageY-offset.top-(closestHandle.height()/2)-(parseInt(closestHandle.css("borderTopWidth"),10)||0)-(parseInt(closestHandle.css("borderBottomWidth"),10)||0)+(parseInt(closestHandle.css("marginTop"),10)||0)};if(!this.handles.hasClass("ui-state-hover")){this._slide(b,index,normValue)}this._animateOff=true;return true},_mouseStart:function(a){return true},_mouseDrag:function(a){var b={x:a.pageX,y:a.pageY},normValue=this._normValueFromMouse(b);this._slide(a,this._handleIndex,normValue);return false},_mouseStop:function(a){this.handles.removeClass("ui-state-active");this._mouseSliding=false;this._stop(a,this._handleIndex);this._change(a,this._handleIndex);this._handleIndex=null;this._clickOffset=null;this._animateOff=false;return false},_detectOrientation:function(){this.orientation=(this.options.orientation==="vertical")?"vertical":"horizontal"},_normValueFromMouse:function(a){var b,pixelMouse,percentMouse,valueTotal,valueMouse;if(this.orientation==="horizontal"){b=this.elementSize.width;pixelMouse=a.x-this.elementOffset.left-(this._clickOffset?this._clickOffset.left:0)}else{b=this.elementSize.height;pixelMouse=a.y-this.elementOffset.top-(this._clickOffset?this._clickOffset.top:0)}percentMouse=(pixelMouse/b);if(percentMouse>1){percentMouse=1}if(percentMouse<0){percentMouse=0}if(this.orientation==="vertical"){percentMouse=1-percentMouse}if(this.options.isRTL){percentMouse=1-percentMouse}valueTotal=this._valueMax()-this._valueMin();valueMouse=this._valueMin()+percentMouse*valueTotal;return this._trimAlignValue(valueMouse)},_start:function(a,b){var c={handle:this.handles[b],value:this.value()};if(this.options.values&&this.options.values.length){c.value=this.values(b);c.values=this.values()}return this._trigger("start",a,c)},_slide:function(a,b,c){var d,newValues,allowed;if(this.options.values&&this.options.values.length){d=this.values(b?0:1);if((this.options.values.length===2&&this.options.range===true)&&((b===0&&c>d)||(b===1&&c<d))){c=d}if(c!==this.values(b)){newValues=this.values();newValues[b]=c;allowed=this._trigger("slide",a,{handle:this.handles[b],value:c,values:newValues});d=this.values(b?0:1);if(allowed!==false){this.values(b,c,true)}}}else{if(c!==this.value()){allowed=this._trigger("slide",a,{handle:this.handles[b],value:c});if(allowed!==false){this.value(c)}}}},_stop:function(a,b){var c={handle:this.handles[b],value:this.value()};if(this.options.values&&this.options.values.length){c.value=this.values(b);c.values=this.values()}this._trigger("stop",a,c)},_change:function(a,b){if(!this._keySliding&&!this._mouseSliding){var c={handle:this.handles[b],value:this.value()};if(this.options.values&&this.options.values.length){c.value=this.values(b);c.values=this.values()}this._trigger("change",a,c)}},value:function(a){if(arguments.length){this.options.value=this._trimAlignValue(a);this._refreshValue();this._change(null,0)}return this._value()},values:function(a,b){var c,newValues,i;if(arguments.length>1){this.options.values[a]=this._trimAlignValue(b);this._refreshValue();this._change(null,a)}if(arguments.length){if($.isArray(arguments[0])){c=this.options.values;newValues=arguments[0];for(i=0;i<c.length;i+=1){c[i]=this._trimAlignValue(newValues[i]);this._change(null,i)}this._refreshValue()}else{if(this.options.values&&this.options.values.length){return this._values(a)}else{return this.value()}}}else{return this._values()}},_setOption:function(a,b){var i,valsLength=0;if($.isArray(this.options.values)){valsLength=this.options.values.length}$.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply(this,arguments);switch(a){case"disabled":if(b){this.handles.filter(".ui-state-focus").blur();this.handles.removeClass("ui-state-hover");this.handles.attr("disabled","disabled");this.element.addClass("ui-disabled")}else{this.handles.removeAttr("disabled");this.element.removeClass("ui-disabled")}break;case"orientation":this._detectOrientation();this.element.removeClass("ui-slider-horizontal ui-slider-vertical").addClass("ui-slider-"+this.orientation);this._refreshValue();break;case"isRTL":this.element.toggleClass("ui-slider-rtl",b);this._refreshValue();break;case"value":this._animateOff=true;this._refreshValue();this._change(null,0);this._animateOff=false;break;case"values":this._animateOff=true;this._refreshValue();for(i=0;i<valsLength;i+=1){this._change(null,i)}this._animateOff=false;break}},_value:function(){var a=this.options.value;a=this._trimAlignValue(a);return a},_values:function(a){var b,vals,i;if(arguments.length){b=this.options.values[a];b=this._trimAlignValue(b);return b}else{vals=this.options.values.slice();for(i=0;i<vals.length;i+=1){vals[i]=this._trimAlignValue(vals[i])}return vals}},_trimAlignValue:function(a){if(a<=this._valueMin()){return this._valueMin()}if(a>=this._valueMax()){return this._valueMax()}var b=(this.options.step>0)?this.options.step:1,valModStep=(a-this._valueMin())%b;alignValue=a-valModStep;if(Math.abs(valModStep)*2>=b){alignValue+=(valModStep>0)?b:(-b)}return parseFloat(alignValue.toFixed(5))},_valueMin:function(){return this.options.min},_valueMax:function(){return this.options.max},_refreshValue:function(){var a=this.options.range,o=this.options,self=this,animate=(!this._animateOff)?o.animate:false,valPercent,_set={},lastValPercent,value,valueMin,valueMax;if(this.options.values&&this.options.values.length){this.handles.each(function(i,j){valPercent=(self.values(i)-self._valueMin())/(self._valueMax()-self._valueMin())*100;valPercent=(self.options.isRTL?100-valPercent:valPercent);_set[self.orientation==="horizontal"?"left":"bottom"]=valPercent+"%";$(this).stop(1,1)[animate?"animate":"css"](_set,o.animate);if(self.options.range===true){if(self.orientation==="horizontal"){if(i===0){self.range.stop(1,1)[animate?"animate":"css"](self.options.isRTL?{right:(100-valPercent)+"%"}:{left:valPercent+"%"},o.animate)}if(i===1){self.range[animate?"animate":"css"]({width:((self.options.isRTL?-1:+1)*(valPercent-lastValPercent))+"%"},{queue:false,duration:o.animate})}}else{if(i===0){self.range.stop(1,1)[animate?"animate":"css"](self.options.isRTL?{top:(100-valPercent)+"%"}:{bottom:(valPercent)+"%"},o.animate)}if(i===1){self.range[animate?"animate":"css"]({height:((self.options.isRTL?-1:+1)*(valPercent-lastValPercent))+"%"},{queue:false,duration:o.animate})}}}lastValPercent=valPercent})}else{value=this.value();valueMin=this._valueMin();valueMax=this._valueMax();valPercent=(valueMax!==valueMin)?(value-valueMin)/(valueMax-valueMin)*100:0;valPercent=(self.options.isRTL?100-valPercent:valPercent);_set[self.orientation==="horizontal"?"left":"bottom"]=valPercent+"%";this.handle.stop(1,1)[animate?"animate":"css"](_set,o.animate);if(a==="min"&&this.orientation==="horizontal"){this.range.stop(1,1)[animate?"animate":"css"]({width:(self.options.isRTL?100-valPercent:valPercent)+"%"},o.animate)}if(a==="max"&&this.orientation==="horizontal"){this.range[animate?"animate":"css"]({width:(self.options.isRTL?valPercent:100-valPercent)+"%"},{queue:false,duration:o.animate})}if(a==="min"&&this.orientation==="vertical"){this.range.stop(1,1)[animate?"animate":"css"]({height:(self.options.isRTL?100-valPercent:valPercent)+"%"},o.animate)}if(a==="max"&&this.orientation==="vertical"){this.range[animate?"animate":"css"]({height:(self.options.isRTL?valPercent:100-valPercent)+"%"},{queue:false,duration:o.animate})}}}});$.extend($.ui.slider,{version:"1.8.9"})}(jQuery));
```

```css
/* Overrides for right-to-left sliders. */

.ui-slider-horizontal.ui-slider-rtl .ui-slider-range-min { left: auto; right: 0; }
.ui-slider-horizontal.ui-slider-rtl .ui-slider-range-max { left: 0; right: auto; }

.ui-slider-vertical.ui-slider-rtl .ui-slider-range-min { top: 0; bottom: auto; }
.ui-slider-vertical.ui-slider-rtl .ui-slider-range-max { top: auto; bottom: 0; }
```

Comment: But there is no proper documentation for same, do you have working example for the same ?

Comment: @PardeepJain the above link is the working example, I haven't tried myself anyways.

Comment: sorry for that, I have updated the link, will try to bring the code within the answer

Comment: The code already copied to the answer

Answer (score 10):

I don't like the patch from http://keith-wood.name/rtlsliders.html simply because it patches an old version of jQuery UI, and unfortunately they did not incorporate it into the main code yet (why?!).

Another option would be to reverse the `min` and `max`, but the widget doesn't allow `min > max`, so I tricked it. I did `{ min: max * -1, max: min * -1 }`, and then used `value * -1`.

Example time: say you want a slider that lets the user choose a number between `1` and `10`.

```
{ min: 1, max: 10 }
Generates: <[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10]>
{ min: -10, max: -1 }
Generates: <[-10][-9][-8][-7][-6][-5][-4][-3][-2][-1]>
```

Now it looks from right to left! Now you simply need to multiply whatever result you get from the slider by `-1`, so when he moves the slider the where `7` in RTL would be and you'd get a `-7`, simply multiply by `-1` it before using. This also works for ranges.

You can obviously use other mathematical systems but I found this to be the simplest to comprehend.

Comment: Since `http://keith-wood.name/rtlsliders.html` doesn't work with latest jQuery UI version, I prefer this answer over the accepted one.

Comment: hi, Can you please tell how did you applied { min: max * -1, max: min * -1 } ?

Comment: @ameya see the original question, it was applied as the options the the slider method (the jQuery widget). This is a mathematical solution so it would work with any slider implementation.